# receiving errors while working on Advance look up column in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, lookup-column, administration, error-handling

I am working in SharePoint 2013, I received errors while I was working on Advance look up.

Two errors one after the other:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching
>   element
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
>   predicate)
>
> at
>   AnjLab.SharePoint.RichControls.Fields.RichLookupField.DependedLookUp()
>
> at AnjLab.SharePoint.RichControls.Fields.RichLookupField.Update()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldEditPage.BtnOk_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
>   (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains
>   no matching element
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
>   predicate)
>
> at
>   AnjLab.SharePoint.RichControls.Fields.RichLookupField.DependedLookUp()
>
> at AnjLab.SharePoint.RichControls.Fields.RichLookupField.Update()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldEditPage.BtnOk_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>
> at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)